# how to connect android app to a RoR database

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails

i have a android app, how can i save data from the android app to a RoR database?

thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand you have got server app on Rails and local Android app.

Best idea is to use all benefits of REST. Using REST you'll have some kind of API for your Rails app. So your connection will be through HTTP protocol via POST and GET requests

Comment: I thought it is not an answer but just a .. you know .. an idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you have got server app on Rails and local Android app.

Best idea is to use all benefits of REST. Using REST you'll have some kind of API for your Rails app. So your connection will be through HTTP protocol via POST and GET requests